# Autocomplete method not called using AutoExtender

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, autocomplete, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have Ajax AutoExtender control asociated with textbox. Suggested data are selected from database. But my AutoComplete code is not even fired. What can be wrong with the code? Thanks.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSports" runat="server" CssClass="textbox" placeholder="Sport"></asp:TextBox> 
<ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" MinimumPrefixLength="1" ServicePath="~/AutoComplete.asmx" CompletionSetCount="20" CompletionInterval="0000" EnableCaching="true" UseContextKey="True" ServiceMethod="GetCompletionList" TargetControlID="txtSports" runat="server"></ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

AutoComplete.asmx file:

```
Imports System.Web.Services.Protocols
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports AjaxControlToolkit

' To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line.
<System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()> _
<System.Web.Services.WebService(Namespace:="http://tempuri.org/")> _
<System.Web.Services.WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _
<ToolboxItem(False)> _
Public Class AutoComplete
    Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

    <System.Web.Services.WebMethodAttribute, System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethodAttribute> _
    Public Shared Function GetCompletionList(prefixText As String, count As Integer, contextKey As String) As String()
        Dim listString As New List(Of String)()
        Dim connStr As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("SportovniPlanetaCS").ConnectionString.ToString()
        Using conn As New SqlConnection(connStr)
            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand((Convert.ToString("SELECT Sport, SportId FROM Sports WHERE  Sport LIKE @Sport")))
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sport", prefixText)
            conn.Open()
            Dim dr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            If dr.HasRows Then
                While dr.Read()
                    listString.Add(AutoCompleteExtender.CreateAutoCompleteItem(dr("Sport").ToString(), dr("SportId").ToString()))
                End While
            End If
        End Using
        Dim str As String() = listString.ToArray()
        Return str
    End Function

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Well i Don't think you need to use a separate `WebService` for it. you could create a web method and make it work.

You could see example here...

[AutoComplete Demonstration](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/ajaxcontroltoolkitsamplesite/autocomplete/autocomplete.aspx)

Comment: I tried it, but the method was not called either. The problem maybe is, when I click in design view of .aspx page on Auto generate autocomplete method, it return a error, that code behind was not found.

Comment: If page is not found..then you must be redirecting to wrong page...!!! Set a breakpoint on your method and try...you could check your response in fiddler or firebug...

Comment: When I set breakpoint on that method, it is not stopped in that place. So the mehtod is not called.

Answer (score 0):

In AjaxToolKit add

OnClientItemSelected="ClientItemSelected"

---

add javascript

---

function ClientItemSelected(source, e) 
{

source.get_element().value = (document.all) ? e._item.innerText : e._item.textContent;

var str = $('#<%=txtsports.ClientID %>').val();

}